# adding android:tragetSdkVersion= "14" in maifest for application developed for 2.3.3 version, is it a good idea?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I want to add `android:tragetSdkVersion= "14"` in my manifest but I'm consufed as initially I developed my application for 2.3.3 version. So I used `TabActivity` for that. But `TabActivity` is deprecated in 4.0 version and according to the documentation, including `android:tragetSdkVersion= "14"` means system will not impose any forward compatibility to the app. So I wonder if it is good idea to include `android:tragetSdkVersion= "14"` in my manifest.

Comment: I guess we can always use minSdkVersion.

Comment: yes we can always use minSdkVersion. But should I use android:tragetSdkVersion= "14" if I'm using TabActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it working on sdk 14, why are you leaving TabActivity in your code?

Otherwise, don't make sdk14 your target, and better to prevent users with version 4.0 or higher to install your application

Answer (score 0):

You should use the v4 support libraries if you target higher SDK versions and also provide a minSdk:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

here is info about the support libraries

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html